# Evaluating an integral numerically at many points

Tags: interpolation, quadrature, integration

Given a real function $f$, how can one efficiently evaluate $\int_0^{a_i}f(x)dx$ for millions of different $a_i$?

Applying a standard [quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration) method (such as [Simpson's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) or [Gaussian quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature)) will incur an independent cost for each $a_i$, since in general $f(x)$ will need to be evaluated at an entirely different set of points for each $a_i$.

I would prefer to pre-generate/calculate a data structure at substantial initial cost, if the integral can then be evaluated from this data structure cheaply, for different $a_i$.

One possibility I see is to evaluate the integral at a regular array of points $x_j=a_{max}j/n$ (which would allow reuse of points in Simpson's method), and then to "correct" this integral on final evaluation with a small $\int_{a_{max}j/n}^{a_i}f(x)dx$ which can be evaluated with a very low-order Gaussian quadrature because $j$ can be chosen to make this correction interval small. Although probably accurate, it seems like this method may give rise to discontinuities at the half-way points between subsequent $j$.

Another possibility may be to fit cubic splines to a regular array of points (evaluated from Simpson's method) and then rely on these to interpolate the integral.

I would rather follow an established approach if there is one.

Comment: A lot will depend on a) the range of the $a_i$ and b) even more on the smoothness and oscillatory behaviour of $f(x)$. If $f(x)$ has discontinuities (or in its derivatives) in $[0, a_i]$ but not in $[0, a_j]$ with $a_i\ > a_j$ than you can not have a single optimal quadrature.

Comment: @GertVdE $f$ is well-behaved (it's the integrand at the end of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2751706/86969) question) and $a_i$ range over a "limited" interval over which they are approximately uniformly distributed.

Comment: Have you tried to simply split the integral into subintervals $[a_i, a_{i+1}]$, calculate it there appropriately (if possible via some low-order formula) and then sum up? That scales as O(N), and ammounts to some low order Runge-Kutta scheme (with varying timesteps) when viewed as a differential equation, i.e. $dI/dy = f(y)$ where $I(y) = \int_0^y f(x) dx$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point of @WolfgangBangerth is exactly what I mentionend in my comment, so I'd always try this first. In the best case, with millions of partitions $[a_{i},a_{i+1}]_{i\in \{0,\ldots,N-1\}}$ (where $a_{i} < a_{i+1}$), the length of these is quite small such that some low-order method could be appropriate. This will require roughly $N \times (s-1)$ function evaluations, where $s$ is the number of evaluations required to integrate one subinterval (e.g., $s=2$ for the trapezoidal rule), and $N \approx 10^6$ should be no problem for a modern PC.

Alternatively, in order to map it on a standard problem, you can consider the integral $I(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dt$ in differential form,
$$
\frac{\partial I(x)}{\partial x} = f(x), \quad \ I(0) = 0.
$$
One can then apply Runge-Kutta or some other standard ODE solver to integrate for $I(x)$ from $x=0$ to $x=a_N$. The steps that are taken in the solution in general won't meet your specified gridpoints $a_i$, thus you need to apply a method called *dense output* which is basically a polynomial interpolation with an order that is appropriate for your solver. Dense output usually requires no or only a few additional function evaluations per step, and thus can save you a lot of effort.

Let's apply this approach to the idea you mentioned: one can integrate the equation using fourth order Runge-Kutta (which in this case directly corresponds to Simpson's rule) with a constant stepsize $h = a_N / M$. Here, the number of steps $M$ should be chosen such that the final solution $I(a_N)$ is accurate, what should be possible with $M \ll N$ in order to justify the overhead over the simple integration mentioned in the beginning.

Then, in each subinterval $[x_{n},\,x_{n+1}]_{n\in \{0,\ldots,N-1\}}$, where $x_{n}=nh$, $I_n=I(x_n)$, $f_n=f(x_n)$, you can apply Hermite interpolation as [see Numerical recipes, 3rd edition, formula (17.2.15)]:
$$I(x_n+\theta h)=(1-\theta)I_n + \theta I_{n+1} + \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\;\;\\ \theta(\theta-1)\Big((1-2\theta)(I_{n+1}-I_n)+(\theta-1)h f_n + \theta hf_{n+1}\Big)$$

This is a cubic interpolation polynomial which is appropriate for the fourth-order Runge-Kutta method -- one order less than the local order is ok, as you don't use the interpolant for taking further steps, see e.g. [here](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~ljay/publications.dir/EACM_Dense_Output.pdf). All that remains to do is to adjust the parameter $\theta$ such that $a_i = x_n+\theta h$ (you have to do that repeatedly for each $a_i \in [x_n,x_{n+1}]$).

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you've ordered the points so that $0<a_1<a_2<\ldots<a_n$. Then you have of course that
$$
  \int_0^{a_2} f(x) dx
  =
  \int_0^{a_1} f(x) dx +
  \int_{a_1}^{a_2} f(x) dx.
$$
In other words, if you have previously computed the integrals from zero to $a_1$ through some numerical method, then computing the integral from zero to $a_2$ can reuse this information, and all you have to do is now compute the integral from $a_1$ to $a_2$, which you can do independently.

The same applied for all of the other integrals, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The standard method is [double-exponential sinc quadrature](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2005-74-250/S0025-5718-04-01724-7/S0025-5718-04-01724-7.pdf). The fast convergence requires some regularity assumptions on the integrand, namely that it is the restriction to the real line of a complex differentiable function bounded on a Bernstein ellipse.